# Problems with roslaunch bringup Kinova Jaco arms

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, kinova

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi. I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 and ROS Kinetic. I recently upgraded from 14.04 and Indigo. Everything worked fine before, but now, when I try to launch my Kinova Jaco arms, I'm getting an error and I don't understand how to fix it. I've never gotten an error like this before, and I tried googling but I can't seem to find out what to do to fix this. Any help you can provide would be very greatly appreciated! Thanks very much!

The command I run :

```
roslaunch kinova_bringup kinova_robot.launch kinova_robotType:=j2n6s300 kinova_robotName:=left kinova_robotSerial:=PJ00900006WO5044820
```

The Error I get

```
PARAMETERS
 * /kinova_number_of_robots: 2
 * /kinova_robots: [{'serial': 'PJ00...
 * /left_driver/connection_type: USB
 * /left_driver/ethernet/local_broadcast_port: 25025
 * /left_driver/ethernet/local_cmd_port: 25000
 * /left_driver/ethernet/local_machine_IP: 192.168.100.100
 * /left_driver/ethernet/subnet_mask: 255.255.255.0
 * /left_driver/jointSpeedLimitParameter1: 10
 * /left_driver/jointSpeedLimitParameter2: 20
 * /left_driver/robot_name: left
 * /left_driver/robot_type: j2n6s300
 * /left_driver/serial_number: PJ00900006WO5044820
 * /left_driver/torque_parameters/publish_torque_with_gravity_compensation: False
 * /left_driver/torque_parameters/use_estimated_COM_parameters: False
 * /left_driver/use_jaco_v1_fingers: False
 * /robot_description: <?xml version="1....
 * /rosdistro: kinetic
 * /rosversion: 1.12.14

NODES
  /
    left_driver (kinova_driver/kinova_arm_driver)
    left_state_publisher (robot_state_publisher/robot_state_publisher)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

process[left_driver-1]: started with pid [3364]
process[left_state_publisher-2]: started with pid [3365]
[ INFO] [1574859834.374096419]: kinova_robotType is j2n6s300.
[ INFO] [1574859834.375342370]: kinova_robotName is left.
[FATAL] [1574859834.378008786]: USBCommandLayerUbuntu.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
kinova_arm_driver: /home/alexis/catkin_ws/src/kinova-ros/kinova_driver/src/kinova_api.cpp:26: void* kinova::KinovaAPI::initCommandLayerFunction(const char*): Assertion `function_pointer != NULL' failed.
[left_driver-1] process has died [pid 3364, exit code -6, cmd /home/alexis/catkin_ws/devel/lib/kinova_driver/kinova_arm_driver j2n6s300 __name:=left_driver __log:=/home/alexis/.ros/log/467f01d0-1116-11ea-8784-8ca982d60e8e/left_driver-1.log].
log file: /home/alexis/.ros/log/467f01d0-1116-11ea-8784-8ca982d60e8e/left_driver-1*.log
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/338719/problems-with-roslaunch-bringup-kinova-jaco-arms/) by [blockale23](https://answers.ros.org/users/49828/blockale23/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2019-11-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-11-27**:
As to your problem: have you rebuilt the workspace after upgrading (ie: remove the `build` and `devel` folders and run `catkin_make` (or `catkin build`) again)?

Looking at [the readme](https://github.com/Kinovarobotics/kinova-ros/blob/acf6e6d2e3e9cfb2a51507f1d190ec27df8e569b/README.md) it appears things should-just-work on Kinetic.

The `USBCommandLayerUbuntu.so` is a library that is distributed with `kinova_driver` ([here](https://github.com/Kinovarobotics/kinova-ros/tree/acf6e6d2e3e9cfb2a51507f1d190ec27df8e569b/kinova_driver/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu)) and installed [here](https://github.com/Kinovarobotics/kinova-ros/blob/acf6e6d2e3e9cfb2a51507f1d190ec27df8e569b/kinova_driver/CMakeLists.txt#L121-L127).

There don't appear to be any specific build or installation instructions, so I assume it should work in both the `devel` as well as the `install` space.

The error essentially tells you that the search path for libraries does not include the location that holds the `.so` file(s).

**Comment by [blockale23](https://answers.ros.org/users/49828/blockale23/) on 2019-11-27**:
Yes, I did rebuild the workspace after upgrading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seemed there were multiple issues. First, for some reason the library you showed me was missing in my folder. I ended up re-installing kinova-ros completely to ensure there weren't any other things missing. That fixed some problems but not all. Then, I eliminated any specifications of the arm (name, serial number) and I was finally able to bring up one arm. Then when I tried again to bringup a specific arm using the name and serial number it all of a sudden worked. Strange. But thank you very much for your help in solving this issue.

---

Originally posted by [blockale23](https://answers.ros.org/users/49828/blockale23/) with karma: 16 on 2019-11-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0